# Objective C / Object Orientated Pointers

Tags: objective-c, oop, pointers

I have been playing with objective C a little and am finding it a great language..

Coming from C# i found pointers a little hard but now i understand the concept and how to use them..

ie:

```
MyObject* x = [[myObject alloc] callinitializer];
```

which create a new object on the heap and a pointer on the stack..

but can somebody please explain why to access the objects properties you do this:

```
[x setsomeprop: @"I Like Pizza"];
```

instead of this:

```
[*x setsomeprop: @"With Pineapple"];
```

without the dereferencing star arent we just working with the pointer instead of the object itself??

Confuesd!

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The bracket syntax is a language feature specifically for objects - it dereferences the pointer automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot thats awesome!.. i've been tearing my hair out thinking i was stupid cause not one of the obj-c books i've read said that i just shrugged and assumed that was happening, Oh btw did i get the stack / heap terminology right?

Answer (score 0):

Partly this is just a result of how method dispatch works in a dynamic language like Objective-C. There's almost nothing useful you can do with a dereferenced object pointer in Objective-C.

Given that all objects are stored on the heap, and manage their own lifecycle with retain/release (or via garbage collection), a pointer to the object is exactly what you want to use in 99% of all situations.

As it turns out, essentially the same mechanism is used in C# and Java - object references are pointers, which is why assigning one reference to another makes them point at the same object, rather than copying the object.